# image url to canvas and save

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to load an image from a URL to the canvas, and then display the image to be saved. I can display the image in the canvas but when I trying to display the image as a base64 string it it blank. Here is what I can come up with so far just need help on the last part.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
};

imageObj.src = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4NP3xwj-ZMI/UXU8RT1k02I/AAAAAAAACEU/88knXDu2MeQ/s72-c/music3g1.JPG';

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a couple of things to know.

1. When you draw an image to a canvas from a source outside of the domain the html is in, it flags the `dirty` flag on the canvas. This makes it so you can't use the `.toDataURL()` function. It is mainly a security issue.
2. `var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;` is called before the image is actually drawn to the canvas. You'll need to get the data url and set the src within the onload function of the image.